# Given $a,b,c\ni \mathbb {R_{>0}}$ s.t. $abc\left(a+b+c\right)=1$, find the maximum of $\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

> Given $a,b,c\ni \mathbb {R_{>0}}$ s.t. $abc\left(a+b+c\right)=1$, find the maximum of $\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)$.

I have been confused by this question for a week, but I can't find any clues of solving this question. Although, I find that 
$$\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)=bc+a\left(a+b+c\right)$$
and 
$$abc\left(a+b+c\right)=bc\times a\left(a+b+c\right)=1.$$
I can only say that the minimum is $2$, but not the maximum. If you solve it or you find some clues that may help solving this question, please tell me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first equation
$$(a+b)(a+c)=a(a+b+c)+bc=\frac{1}{bc}+bc.$$
Now let $b=c=x$. Then by solving $ax^2\left(a+2x\right)=1$ we have that given $x>0$, for 
$$a=\frac{-x^2+\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x}>0$$
the condition $abc\left(a+b+c\right)=1$ is satisfied.
Hence, by letting $x\to +\infty$, it follows that the "maximum" of $\frac{1}{bc}+bc=\frac{1}{x^2}+x^2$ is $+\infty$ .

Comment: Are you sure that it's fair, which you are doing? See please my post.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I was writing my post and I did not read all your answers.

Comment: @MichaelRozenber I did not downvote your answer. If you are annoyed because of my answer I will remove it. I am not  here  to compete with you.

Comment: In another case I would be understand you. OK. I understand you even now. I did not think that you down-voted of course.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum does not exist.

Try $c=1$, $b=\frac{-a(a+1)+\sqrt{a^2(a+1)^2+4a}}{2a}$ and  $a\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: @Isaac YIU Math Studio I added something. See now.

Comment: I think my teacher has made some mistakes lol. But thanks for answering XD

Comment: @Isaac YIU Math Studio About which mistake do you say? Say me please. It was your down-voting? If so, it's really not fair! I wanted to help you and you...

Comment: I don't know if my teacher is making a right question, but it is good for me to know that the maximum does not exist because I couldn't find a solution for it. So don't care about it. Btw, I have upvoted you!